# Установка grub2 на GPT через UEFI

Tags: archlinux, grub

Привет, Руткод.

Я пытаюсь поставить **grub2** на диск размеченный под **GPT** на машине с поддержкой **UEFI**, после чего ’успешно’ получаю ошибку «**Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key**».

Теперь подробнее что я делаю для достижения такого эффекта:

1. В настройках биоса материнки выставляю **Enable UEFI booting**.
2. С помощью графического установщика арч выполняю все пункты установки кроме разметки диска и установки загрузчика.
3. Диск же размечаю с помощью gdisk: 400мб fat32 «EFI System partition»; 45гб ext4 «Linux filesystem data». Первый монтируется в `/boot/efi` а второй в корень.
4. Устанавливаю `grub2` в первый раздел

   grub_efi_x86_64-install --root-directory=/boot/efi --boot-directory=/boot/efi/efi --bootloader-id=arch_grub --no-floppy --recheck --debug
5. Копирую настройки для «GRUB2 entry in the Firmware Boot Manager» (извините, не знаю как правильно перевести). Для надёжности аж в три места.

   cp /boot/efi/efi/arch_grub/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/shellx64.efi

   cp /boot/efi/efi/arch_grub/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/efi/shellx64.efi

   cp /boot/efi/efi/arch_grub/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/efi/shell/shellx64.efi;
6. Настраиваю grub.cfg, но это уже не суть важно, ибо из сообщения видно: **система до загрузки grub2 не доходит**.

Может у кого есть идеи что я сделал не так и как с этим бороться?

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую почитать вики арча. Это одна из лучших вики, которую я когда либо видел. Читать желательно английскую версию, там всё отлично описано.